# how can i send failed tests screenshots to reportportal. I am using Java + TestNG framework

Tags: java, reporting, reportportal

I tried below code to send screenshots of  failed tests to reportPortal, but its not working for me.Can somebody please help here

```
public ReportPortalMessage failedScrenshot(String methodName) 
    {
        ReportPortalMessage message = null;
        String time = pg.subGrpUnique_monthdate();
        File srcfile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        java.util.Date d= new java.util.Date();
        try
        {
                org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(srcfile, new File("./ScreenShots/"+d.toString().replace(":", "_")+".png"));                               message = new ReportPortalMessage(srcfile, rp_message);
            LOGGER.info("Screenshot taken.");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.info("Unable to take screenshot.");
        }
         LOGGER.info(message);
         return message;   
    }
```

Comment: you would need to share what is ReportPortalMessage class as currently it seems you've just set it to null.

Answer (score 1):

There are examples which do exactly what you want:

- A simple one: [ScreenshotOnFailureTestSimple.java](https://github.com/reportportal/examples-java/blob/master/example-testng-logback/src/main/java/com/epam/reportportal/example/testng/logback/logging/ScreenshotOnFailureTestSimple.java)
- A more complex one: [ScreenshotOnFailureTestExtension.java](https://github.com/reportportal/examples-java/blob/master/example-testng-logback/src/main/java/com/epam/reportportal/example/testng/logback/extension/ScreenshotOnFailureTestExtension.java)

For the first one example screenshot will appear in `@AfterMethod`:
[image: Test view]
[image: Method view]

For the latter example screenshot will appear in the same test method:
[image: Test view]
[image: Method view]